# CAML In clause - Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: web-services, jquery, caml-query, caml

I get a 'Value does not fall within the expected range' error from the following CAML.

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <In>
      <FieldRef Name="ID"/>
      <Values>
        <Value Type="Counter">5</Value>
        <Value Type="Counter">6</Value>
      </Values>
    </In>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I'm using a [jQuery Library for SharePoint](http://spservices.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Can you please provide us with the section calling the CAML?

Comment: Check out the EDIT of the question...

Answer (score 2):

Although Microsoft added the  clause to CAML in SP2010 I don't think they updated the SOAP WebServices api to support it.

See here: https://spservices.codeplex.com/discussions/457313

Answer (score 0):

Try if Type="Integer" would work with ID when used inside <Values>. If not, convert <In> to multiple <Or> clauses. Workaround, yes, but internal ID field might be a bit special when used in CAML queries.

Comment: Type="Integer" made no difference. I'd like to avoid the workaround and try to understand what causes the issue.

Comment: You can always use decompiler to learn why it doesn't work, but a friendly advise: sometimes with SharePoint it's just better to move on if you want to get things done.